# Excel =if conditional question

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

In Excel I need to do the following:

If cell A1 contains the text, "Toronto" then in B1 I need to put "X"

So I guess a formula in B1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=IF(A1="Toronto","X","")
is the if format. if you are confused about excel formula's simply press the equals key in a blank cell and click the insert format command (Fx) and it will walk you through the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A1="Toronto","X",FALSE)
```

in B1, and replace FALSE with whatever you wish to put in the cell if it's not Toronto. If you simply want to leave it blank use "".

Answer (score 0):

maybe in B1 if(A1 = "Toronto","X","Y")

Answer (score 0):

If you want for Cell B1 to remain Blank unless A1 contains the text "Toronto" you could use the following formula in cell B1: =IF(A1="Toronto","X","")